# Alinhamento de texto

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer que um texto apareça alinhado.
Esse texto está em uma variável em ruby on rails.
Como segue:

```
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 400 }'>

 <div class="col-12" style="width: 250px;height: 350px; padding: 0;margin: 0;margin-right: 100px;text-align: center;">  

   <div class="col-12 col-no-left">
     <a class="service-card" href="/servico/<%= service.permalink %>">
     <h3 class="title" style="text-align: center;"><%= service.name %></h3>
     <p class="description" style="text-align: justify;"><%=service.description.truncate(250).html_safe  %>
    <p class="btn">ver mais</p></p>
    <span><%= service.categories.map(&:name).join(',') %></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

O texto não aparece justificado!
Podem me ajudar? grato!

Comment: Você tem um `text-align: center;` mandando centralizar o conteúdo da div. Você quer centralizar ou justificar?

Comment: ruby? gentileza coloca tags ruby, acho melhor retirar `text-align: center;` e veja antes @bfavaretto disse.

Comment: @KingRider Eu retirei a tag ruby porque a dúvida não é sobre ruby (apesar de o código também usar essa linguagem).

Comment: Precisa ver se o parágrafo está ocupando a largura da div superior. Pode ser que o texto esteja justificado, mas a "caixinha" dele esteja menor e alinhada à esquerda. Acrescente um `border: 1px solid red` nele pra ver melhor (ou use o inspetor do seu browser para visualizar o elemento).

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer justificar o texto que vai estar na classe `description`.

No caso nesta linha de código:

```
<p class="description" style="text-align: justify;"><%=service.description.truncate(250).html_safe  %>
```

Como o texto não está sendo justificado, tente altar a parte `style="text-align: justify;` para `style="text-align: justify !important;"`.

Se isso não funcionar, poste seu codigo completo com o `css` para que seja feita uma analise mais detalhada.